# htmlunit How Call dll function

Tags: dll, htmlunit, invocation

```
final ActiveXComponent activeXComponent = new ActiveXComponent("CLSID:0CA54D3F-CEAE-48AF-9A2B-31909CB9515D");
webClient.getOptions().setActiveXNative(true);
```

The following is the content of the DLL function

How do I call it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

HtmlUnit simulates real browsers.

So you usually have a web page which loads this ActiveX component and calls its properties and methods.

E.g.:

```html
<script>
     function createFile() {    
         var object = new ActiveXObject("CLSID:0CA54D3F-CEAE-48AF-9A2B-31909CB9515D");
     }
</script>
```